# Apache camel Consumers

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a good understanding of camel producers, but I can not wrap my head around the various camel consumers. Particularly the event driven consumer and the polling consumers, how does camel know to call the callbacks for these consumers?

What is the general flow for the consumers?

Answer (score 3):

**Event Driven Consumer**

An event driven consumer will trigger whenever a certain event "abc" happens - you define what happens after that.

Imagine for example, "when the phone rings" - thereafter "you answer the phone". That's an event driven consumer, where the phone ringing is the event. In camel world, the event could be something like a message arriving on a jms queue.

**Polling Consumer**

A polling consumer must actively check for some condition "xyz" at regular intervals - and then do something after that if that condition is true.

Imagine again, "when you get hungry" - thereafter "you go to the fridge". Let's say you check every 10 minutes to see if you feel hungry - that's a polling consumer. In camel world, you could be polling to see if a file arrived in a specific folder from ftp (and then do something after that).